# Serialize a non-directly related relationship

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, json-api

I have a `Project`, belonging to an artist (a django `User`):

```
class Project:
    artist = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I also have a `Product`, part of a `Project`:

```
class Product:
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

The `artist` is not a direct relationship on the `Product`, but can be found via the `Project`. When serializing, I would like to directly serialize the `artist` in the `Product`, so that is seen as one of the relationships of the `Product` model. I have tried defining an artist property:

```
class Product(models.Model):
...
    @property
    def artist(self):
        return self.project.artist.id
```

And my serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'project', 'artist', 'name', 'description', 'compatibility', 'format', 'type', 'created', 'modified', 'price', 'bought', 'image', 'price_range')
```

But this just puts the artist id as an attribute, not as a relationship. If I remove the `.id`:

```
class Product(models.Model):
...
    @property
    def artist(self):
        return self.project.artist
```

Then it can not be serialized:

```
TypeError: <User: leia-70823> is not JSON serializable
```

How can I serialize this indirect relationship?

### EDIT

This is the current `JSONApi` I get, with the artist id wrongly placed in the `attributes` part:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "product",
    "id": "101",
    "attributes": {
      "artist": 306,
      "name": "big Product",
      "description": "Veniam modi doloremque ducimus. Sit aut officiis suscipit libero itaque. Animi sit molestiae corrupti sed qui impedit.",
      "compatibility": 10,
      "format": 6,
      "type": 2,
      "created": "2001-10-19",
      "modified": "1981-02-20",
      "price": 861,
      "bought": 3939,
      "image": "http:\/\/localhost:15013\/media\/categories\/l2.png",
      "price-range": 1
    },
    "relationships": {
      "project": {
        "data": {
          "type": "project",
          "id": "185"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I would like is to have it placed in the `relationships` part, as is the link to the project.

Comment: Could you add the json that you would like to have, please? (to know the structure of `artist` var

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro: done!

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

To get acutal serialized data of artist(django User), you have make the artist field as `UserSerializer` type

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

then if you need `artist` in `Product` serialized data, modify the Product serializer as follows

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artist = UserSerializer(source='project.artist', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'project', 'artist', 'name', 'description', 'compatibility', 'format', 'type', 'created', 'modified', 'price', 'bought', 'image', 'price_range')
```

Now, the artist key would be the serialized value of `artist` instance itself rather than just id. Hope this is helpful

Also I see you are including almost all the fields of Product in Product serializer. the way you are using is kind of complex. there is better way to do it. use `exclude` in class Meta. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include

Comment: Thanks, but this will serialize the artist as a product attribute. Please notice that JSONApi specifies both attributes and relationships, and my client (EmberData) expects to find exactly that. So this will not work for my case.

Comment: And thanks also for the tip about exclude, I'll probably use that.

Comment: Whr exactly you want the artist to be in the response.. ? And as what key?

Comment: a relationship as defined by the JSONApi standard: `"artist": {
        "data": {
          "type": "user",
          "id": "121"
        }`. Direct relationships are already properly serialized in JSONApi format by `djangorestframework-jsonapi`. Now I need indirect relations to be serialized in a similar way. I would say for that the only thing needed is to tell drf that, apart from the direct relationship, there is an indirect relationship, buy I have no clue how to specify that.